# Error when applying a filter to a pivot table

Tags: python, win32com

I'm trying to apply a filter to a pivot table using the win32com library in Python, but I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\pdf.py", line 13, in <module>
    pivot_field.PivotFilters.Add2(7, None, filter_value)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.11\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 31471, in Add2
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(3054, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((3, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Type
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exceção.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

my python code:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import datetime

excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = True
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\teste.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets('FLV')
pivot_table = worksheet.PivotTables('PivotTable1')
field = '[dCalendario].[DATAS].[DATAS]'
filter_value = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
pivot_field = pivot_table.PivotFields(field)
pivot_field.ClearAllFilters()
pivot_field.PivotFilters.Add2(7, None, filter_value)

workbook.Save()
workbook.Close()
excel.Quit()
```

I need to properly adjust the code so that it can apply the filter to the specified field.